# How to retrieve xml data with value specified

Tags: oracle10g

Hi I'm new to Oracle 10g. I need retrieve the all the sublist from 'fl1'. I know to retrieve tagwise.. How to retrieve tagwise with value specified?

```
 <lists> <Firstlist name = 'fl1'>
     <sublist>s1</sublist>
     <sublist>s2</sublist>
     <sublist>s3</sublist> 
 </firstlist>
 <Firstlist name = 'fl2'>
     <sublist>sb1</sublist>
     <sublist>sb2</sublist>
     <sublist>sb3</sublist> 
 </firstlist> </lists>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's more of a XPATH question:

```
//Firstlist [@name = "fl1"]/sublist
```

So the query could be something like this:

```
SELECT xmlelement("r",xmltype(xmlstr)).extract('//Firstlist [@name = "fl1"]/sublist').getstringval() FROM your_table
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/1165) is a fiddle